# pass google spreadsheet data to a soap web service

Tags: web-services, soap, google-apps-script

I am going to develop a google app script to read data from a google spreadsheet and pass the data to a soap webservice.

Here is the script,

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Get the range of cells that store employee data.
var studentDataRange = ss.getActiveRange();

// For every row of student data, generate an student object.
var studentObjects = getRowsData(sheet, studentDataRange);

  for (var i=0; i<studentObjects.length; i++)
  {
    var student = studentObjects[i];    

    var options = {
      "studentId" : student.studentId,
      "Marks" : student.marks,
      "url" : ss.getUrl(),
     } ;

   //Here i want to pass the options values to a web service.

  }
```

Any one can help me to figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To begin with you will need to build the soap Input XML as defined by the WSDL i.e the options must be converted to an XML of defined format then URL Fetch needs to be used to call the SOAP WS. Sample to get exchange rate

```
    function WS_Currency() {
      var soapIn = XmlService.parse(
        '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></soap12:Envelope>'); // We cannot build the XML from scratch as GAS XML does not allow multiple NS for root
      var soapEnv = soapIn.getRootElement();
//Build your soap message
      var soapNS = soapEnv.getNamespace("soap12");
      var apiNS = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.webserviceX.NET/");
      var soapBody = XmlService.createElement("Body", soapNS);
      var ConversionRate = XmlService.createElement("ConversionRate", apiNS);
      var FromCurrency = XmlService.createElement("FromCurrency", apiNS).setText('USD');
      var ToCurrency = XmlService.createElement("ToCurrency", apiNS).setText('GBP');
      ConversionRate.addContent(FromCurrency);
      ConversionRate.addContent(ToCurrency);
      soapBody.addContent(ConversionRate);
      soapEnv.addContent(soapBody);

// Set the http options here   
      var options =
          {
            "method" : "post",
            "contentType" : "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            "payload" : XmlService.getRawFormat().format(soapIn),
            "muteHttpExceptions" : true
          };
// Call the WS     
      var soapCall= UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL", options);
// Extract the output, yeah this is the only way we need to traverse the received XML :(
      var cRate =  XmlService.parse(soapCall.getContentText()).getRootElement().getChild("Body", soapNS).getChild("ConversionRateResponse", apiNS).getChild("ConversionRateResult", apiNS).getValue();
      Logger.log(cRate);

    }
```